# Django, select queryset overriding values

Tags: python, mysql, django

I am making a simple text game to learn django in the process, and the problem is as follows. The game features rooms and doors between them, the doors have a default state which is change in course of player interaction.

Table 1 for doors:

```
class Location_exit(models.Model):
    exit_from = models.ForeignKey(Location, related_name='exit_from')
    exit_name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    exit_message = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    EXIT_TYPE_CHOICES = (
        (Exit_type.opened.value, 'Open'),
        (Exit_type.closed.value, 'Closed'),
        (Exit_type.hidden.value, 'Hidden'),
    )
    exit_type = models.IntegerField(choices=EXIT_TYPE_CHOICES)
    exit_to=models.ForeignKey(Location, related_name='exit_to')
```

Table 2 for door state as by player:

```
class Location_exit_state(models.Model):
    location_exit = models.ForeignKey(Location_exit)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    exit_type = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

The idea is that when a player first reaches an exit, they get the default state of Open/Closed/Hidden, and should they do something with the door, its new state will be recorded in Table 2. On a next visit that value should be loaded from the second table, while the rest (static) part of data about the door still from Table 1.

With SQL I would go something like

```
SELECT * FROM Location_exit As a WHERE (id, User) NOT IN Location_exit_state
UNION
SELECT a.exit_from, a.exit_name, a.exit_message, a.exit_to, exit_type FROM Location_exit_state LEFT JOIN Location_exit As a
```

But being a total noob in python I have no idea where to look for an equivalent for django. 
Can anyone help?

Comment: Why load the state of the door from table2?
Why not update the state of the door in their own model?

Comment: @Zartch Probably to save a different exit_state for different players?!

Comment: @ Zartch I want the game to be usable by a number of players at a time, with every player having their own set of variables, recording their personal game sate. The doors are pretty much a static element, so there is no sense in making a full copy of doors table for every user. The task is to load as much common data from the main table as possible, and substitute the few values as needed from a player game state.

Comment: @schwobaseggl exactly, sir.

Comment: you don't need the field exit_type in your Location_exit model. It seems redundant. Just add a function that queries for the correct Location_exit_state instance for a given user and takes value from there.

Comment: @schwobasegg how do you offer to set the default door state then? Some doors might be initially closed or hidden.

Comment: @schwobaseggl  "the doors have a default state which is change in course of player interaction" ... "On a next visit that value should be loaded from the second table, while the rest (static) part of data about the door still from Table 1."


It have no sense, if you have to switch the door state, u have to update the door state, not do fancy thing looking the last state of the last player that go throwout the door


If the door state have to change, you must update door Model, in order to get the right state.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would be my way:

```
class Location_exit_state(models.Model):
    location_exit = models.ForeignKey(Location_exit, related_name='user_states')
    ...

class Location_exit(models.Model):
    ...
    default_exit_type = models.SmallPositiveIntegerField(...)        

    def exit_type(self, user):
        try:
            return self.user_states.get(user=user).exit_type
        except:
            self.user_states.create(user=user, exit_type=default_exit_type)
            return default_exit_type
    exit_type.alters_data = True

    def set_new_exit_type(self, user, new_type):
        user_exit_state = self.user_states.get(user=user)
        user_exit_state.exit_type = new_type
        user_exit_state.save()
    set_new_exit_type.alters_data = True
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I get the idea. Should be a valid way to do the task. I will try it and return to you with the result.

Comment: I was able to make a nice working model using the advice you have given,  @schwobaseggl. Thanks again.